# Parser Table Golang

Tags: json, go, parsing

I need to find a way to convert a table to JSON with golang
The table in question looks like:

```
State    Version Support eRSTP Enhancements Bridge Priority Hello Time Max Age Time Transmit Count Forward Delay Max Hops Cost Style    BPDU Guard Timeout VersionForSNMP
Disabled RSTP            On                 0               2 s        20 s         32             15 s          20       STP (16 bit)  Don't shutdown     RSTP
```

Splitting the columns is simple, a split is enough. But notice that there is no pattern of separation in the values, sometimes it is a space, sometimes a tab and sometimes the field is empty
Would there be any way to "parse" this table so that each value goes to its appropriate field?

I hope something like this

[{
"State": "Disabled",
"Version": "RSTP",
...
}]

Comment: There has to be some delimiter that separates the data values, maybe tab, or fixed-width values, otherwise this is not parseable in any language.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that it's not sure what the column headers even are? Going by the example, it could be `State`: Disabled, `Version Support`: RSTP (or `Version`: RSTP and `Support`: [empty]?), `eRSTP Enhancements`: On (or `eRSTP`: On and `Enhancements`: [empty]?), `Bridge Priority`: 0, `Hello Time`: 2 s, `Max Age Time`: 20 s, `Transmit Count`: 32, `Forward Delay`: 15 s, `Max Hops`: 20 etc. First of all, you should clarify that.

Other than that, I can't give you a definite answer, only some ideas:

- if you received this file from someone, ask them to generate it again in a more usable format. This is actually the only sensible idea, but if that doesn't work and you absolutely *have* to import the data...
- this table was obviously built so the columns are aligned with a given tab size (4? 8?), maybe occasionally using spaces instead of tabs. The idea is to determine that tab size and then go by the alignment of the data with the headers. Keep in mind that some columns may be aligned to the right (doesn't look like that going by the example though).
- or you could go by the format of the values. I.e. `State` is always a string (maybe with a limited set of values?), `Version` (or `Version Support` ?) the same, `eRSTP` (or `eRSTP Enhancements`?) is maybe just "On" or "Off",  `Bridge Priority` is always numeric, `Hello Time` is numeric followed by "s" etc. This way you can maybe identify which column the field belongs to even if some fields are empty.
- or some combination of the above :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, and I think it can be solved with the following algorithm, actually:

1. Consider headers and data to be two strings of equal length
2. Iterate from the end of both strings
3. Find all indexes where `headers[i - 1] == " " && headers[i] != " " && data[i - 1] == " " && data [i] != " "`

Once we found those indexes, we can use them to extract the substrings.

This is basically a sliding window of size 2x2.

In first iteration:

```
State    Version Support eRSTP Enhancements Bridge Priority Hello Time Max Age Time Transmit Count Forward Delay Max Hops Cost Style    BPDU Guard Timeout[ V]ersionForSNMP
Disabled RSTP            On                 0               2 s        20 s         32             15 s          20       STP (16 bit)  Don't shutdown    [ R]STP
```

In the second iteration:

```
State    Version Support eRSTP Enhancements Bridge Priority Hello Time Max Age Time Transmit Count Forward Delay Max Hops Cost Style   [ B]PDU Guard Timeout VersionForSNMP
Disabled RSTP            On                 0               2 s        20 s         32             15 s          20       STP (16 bit) [ D]on't shutdown     RSTP
```

And so on.
Now, let's implement this in Go:

```golang
// Input table as a single string
tableString := `State    Version Support eRSTP Enhancements Bridge Priority Hello Time Max Age Time Transmit Count Forward Delay Max Hops Cost Style    BPDU Guard Timeout VersionForSNMP
Disabled RSTP            On                 0               2 s        20 s         32             15 s          20       STP (16 bit)  Don't shutdown     RSTP          `

// Split the table into rows based on newline characters
rows := strings.Split(tableString, "\n")

// If the header and the data rows are not the same, fail
if len(rows[0]) != len(rows[1]) {
    fmt.Println("unaligned table")
    return
    // Other way to handle it may be to pad either the header or the data row
}
var i = len(rows[0]) - 2

var indexes []int
for i >= 0 {

    if string(rows[0][i]) == " " && string(rows[0][i+1]) != " " &&
        string(rows[1][i]) == " " && string(rows[1][i+1]) != " " {
        indexes = append(indexes, i)
    }
    i--
}
```

What we have now are all the indexes that satisfy our requirements.
What's left is just to parse each row using those indexes.

```golang
var results [][]string
for _, row := range rows {
    var prevIndex = 0
    var parsed []string
    for i := len(indexes) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        var subs = row[prevIndex:indexes[i]]
        parsed = append(parsed, subs)
        prevIndex = indexes[i] + 1
    }
    results = append(results, parsed)
}
```

Now, it's not clear if you expect to always have just two rows as your input or not. But I believe that converting from `[][]string` to the JSON output of your liking should be rather easy.

As @rob74 correctly mentioned, we don't actually have context to your domain. For example, the output of my code is:

```
[["State   ","Version Support","eRSTP Enhancements","Bridge Priority","Hello Time","Max Age Time","Transmit Count","Forward Delay","Max Hops","Cost Style   ","BPDU Guard Timeout"],["Disabled","RSTP           ","On                ","0              ","2 s       ","20 s        ","32            ","15 s         ","20      ","STP (16 bit) ","Don't shutdown    "]]
```

But I don't know if "eRSTP Enhancements" is the right name of the column, or if those are two columns, with "eRSTP" value of "On" and with "Enhancements" value of "". That is something you'll have to resolve.